# Coloring a voxel based on position in VTK

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, graphics, 3d, vtk

I have a 3D voxel image that I want to render with VTK.  The data is essentially given as a 3D array, where each element is a tuple `(r, g, b, a)`.  Here is the code that I'm using to generate the data.

```
data_matrix = np.ndarray([500, 500, 500], dtype=([('r','u1'), ('g','u1'), ('b','u1'), ('a','u1')]))
data_matrix.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
for i in range(0, 200):
    for j in range(0, 200):
        for k in range(100, 400):
            data_matrix[i][j][k] = (255, 255, 255, 255)

dataImporter = vtk.vtkImageImport()
data_string = data_matrix.tostring()
dataImporter.CopyImportVoidPointer(data_string, len(data_string))

dataImporter.SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar()
dataImporter.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(4)
dataImporter.SetDataExtent(0, 499, 0, 499, 0, 499)
dataImporter.SetWholeExtent(0, 499, 0, 499, 0, 499)

# generic rendering after this line
```

From my understanding, the `(0, 0, 0, 0)` indicates `a = 0`, and should therefore result in anything that's not the box of interest to be transparent.  However, this does not occur, resulting in the following image where the surrounding is partially transparent.

My guess is that I'm setting up my data pipeline wrong, but I'm not exactly sure what's wrong.  I haven't been able to find any relevant examples yet, and the documentation is a bit terse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can I see how you are rendering it, I dont think your data is wrong. Despite maybe the fact that in your data matrix you are only taking in 3 values

```
data_matrix[i][j][k] = (255, 255, 255, 255)
```

Where you maybe should be taking in 4, and they should not all be 255.

Comment: This is on the border between an answer and what should go into a comment. Could you please make your suggestion a bit more concrete?

Comment: This is quite an old question, I think I ended up using Mayavi because it was easier to work with :)